# Apt-get install bluez and bluetooth for debian noninteractively

Tags: linux, bluetooth, debian, apt-get, bluez

I'm trying to build an image of a debian and install certain applications, all non-interactively. Almost everything works, but alas, almost ...

I `chroot` into my working directory and try to install `bluez` and `bluetooth`:

```
apt-get install -y bluez
apt-get install -y bluetooth
```

However, I get the following error after installing `bluez`

```
Failed to read /proc/cmdline. Ignoring: No such file or directory
[....] Reloading system message bus config...Failed to open connection to "system" message bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "force-reload" failed.
Failed to read /proc/cmdline. Ignoring: No such file or directory
[....] Starting bluetooth:/sbin/start-stop-daemon: nothing in /proc - not mounted?
invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bluetooth:
 bluetooth depends on bluez; however:
  Package bluez is not configured yet.
```

And then `bluetooth` returns an error saying that `bluez` is a dependency that has not been configured.

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/proc/cmdline` is not visible in your chroot environment which is causing the bluez package to fail to configure.

You may be missing the proc mount from `/etc/fstab` :

```
/proc /srv/chroot/wheezy/proc auto bind 0 0
```

Look at the section Pseudo filesystems on [here](https://wiki.debian.org/chroot)

Answer (score 0):

I think before compiling bluez it should be configured,hope below command works

**sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-systemd --enable-experimental  --enable-maintainer-mode**